# Simple jQuery page not working

Tags: jquery

```
  …
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id ="iAmNew">id="iAmNew"</div>
  <script>
    $(#iAmNew).style("border", "4px dotted blue");
  </script>
  …
```

Comment: Hi nandu.com. Please take some extra time formatting your question properly, next time you post on Stack Overflow. Some of your HTML code was not displayed because it was not indented properly. Fixed that for you. -- Btw.: It would be terrific if you actually stated the expected behaviour of your script, instead of just posting some code and letting us guess. It might be obvious here, but that is often not the case. So it's good to get in the right habit... ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because you used a non-existant jQuery method, `.style()` instead of `.css()`. Try:

```
$('#iAmNew').css("border", "4px dotted blue");
```

And, basically, 'what Adam said' (in comments):

> And he forgot the quotes around the selector (just pointing it out).

If you want to use the native JavaScript `style` you should use:

```
document.getElementById('iAmNew').style.border = '4px dotted blue';
```

Reference:

- [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Comment: And he forgot the quotes around the selector (just pointing it out).

Comment: @Adam, good point: I...corrected that without thinking about it. Oops. Good catch. =)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#iAmNew").css("border", "4px dotted blue");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id ="iAmNew">id="iAmNew"</div>

<script>
$("#iAmNew").css("border", "4px dotted blue");</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `style()` method doesn't exist, you're looking for [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/). You also need to put the selector in quotes like so:

```
$("#iAmNew").css("border", "4px dotted blue");
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
$('#iAmNew').css("border", "4px dotted blue");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$("#iAmNew").css("border", "4px dotted blue");`